# Refresh Tab View in swift

Tags: swift, xcode

I made an app with an login system. For those users who logged in I want to show a different content. When i switch through the tabs there is still the content shown, which is loaded when I start the app.
How can I change that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on each controller, you can refresh the display by loading the content in `viewDidAppear` instead of `viewDidLoad`

Comment: Thank you. That helped me :)